# Display parent UL and for the root parent both UL and LI node

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
<ul id="ul_Book1">
<li  id="li_Book1"> Book1 </li>
<ul id="ul_Chap1">
    <li id= "li_Chap1"> Chapter 1</li>
    <ul>
       <li id="li_Sect11"  > Section 1.1 </li>
       <li id="li_Sect12"  > Section 1.2 </li>
       <li id="li_Sect13"  > Section 1.3 </li>
       </ul>
</ul>
<ul id="ul_Chap2">
    <LI  id= "li_Chap2"> Chapter 2</LI>
    <ul>
       <li  id="li_Sect21"  > Section 2.1 </li>
       <li  id="li_Sect22"  > Section 2.2 </li>
       <li  id="li_Sect23"  > Section 2.3 </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
<ul id="ul_Chap3">
    <li  id= "li_Chap3"> Chapter 3</li>
    <ul>
       <li  id="li_Sect31"  > Section 3.1 </li>
       <li  id="li_Sect32"  > Section 3.2 </li>
       <li  id="li_Sect33"  > Section 3.3 </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

function menuDisplayPath(li_id) {

```
var idVal = li_id;

var $obj = $('li').filter(function () { return $(this).attr('id') == idVal; }).parents();

$($obj.get().reverse()).each(function () {
    if ($(this).is("li")) {

        $(this).find('li').each(function () {
            $(this).show();
        });

        $(this).find('Ul').each(function () {
            $(this).show();
        });
    }
});
```

}

When a LI node is selected , say "**Section 3.2**" , I would like to expand/show only  "**Book1-- Chapter3 -- Section 3.2**" and rest of the UL nodes under Book1 should not expand.

But my function  menuDisplayPath(li_id) is expanding all the UL under Book1 and also display all LI's. What am I missing in the function.

Comment: could not come up with a good title for the question. If needed, pls edit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all is expanded on load.

**First**, I corrected many missing double-quotes and extra spaces...
So here is your HTML:

```
<input type="reset" id="reset" value="Expand all">
<ul id="ul_Book1">
    <li id="li_Book1"> Book1 </li>
    <ul id="ul_Chap1">
        <li id="li_Chap1"> Chapter 1</li>
        <ul>
          <li id="li_Sect11"> Section 1.1 </li>
          <li id="li_Sect12"> Section 1.2 </li>
          <li id="li_Sect13"> Section 1.3 </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul id="ul_Chap2">
        <li id="li_Chap2"> Chapter 2</li>
        <ul>
          <li id="li_Sect21"> Section 2.1 </li>
          <li id="li_Sect22"> Section 2.2 </li>
          <li id="li_Sect23"> Section 2.3 </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul id="ul_Chap3">
        <li id="li_Chap3"> Chapter 3</li>
        <ul>
          <li id="li_Sect31"> Section 3.1 </li>
          <li id="li_Sect32"> Section 3.2 </li>
          <li id="li_Sect33"> Section 3.3 </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

And here is the way to hide the other chapters on click of a `li` with a section id:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ul_Book1").on("click","ul ul li", function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().siblings("ul").each(function(){
            $(this).hide(); // Hides all other chapter
        });
    });
    $("#reset").on("click",function(){
        $("#ul_Book1").children("ul").each(function(){
            $(this).show();
        });
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/wrt0ye2c/)

Now... Can't tell you how to display the `<section>` since I didn't see the relevant HTML.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```js
function open($li) {
  $('.content').hide();  
  $li.children().show();
  if ($li.hasClass('section')) $li.parent().parent().children().show();
}

 // test driver
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').click(function (e) { open($(this)); e.stopPropagation(); });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="book">
  <li class="chapter">Chapter One
    <ul class="chapter content">
      <li class="section">Section One<br><i class="content">1.1 contents</i></li>
      <li class="section">Section Two<br><i class="content">1.2 contents</i></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="chapter">Chapter Two
    <ul class="chapter content">
      <li class="section">Section One<br><i class="content">2.1 contents</i></li>
      <li class="section">Section Two<br><i class="content">2.2 contents</i></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Basically you put the section element you want to be open inside the `open($li)` function.

You should also only put `<li>` elements inside `<ul>` elements.
I hope this is what you wanted.